# apache .htaccess mod_rewrite - blocking access to a directory unless the request is done using a specific host

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have searched Google but couldn't figure out how to do this thing:

How can I block access to a specific directory if the request is done on a specific host.

Let me give an example.
I have **a.com** and **b.com** etc. addresses pointing to the same document root (the **/**).

I need to block the access to */sites/private/* directory **unless** the request is coming using *a.com*. The */sites/private/* directory should only be accessible if the request is done using **a.com**.

Thanks.

Comment: So you mean, if somebody clicks on a link on `a.com`? Or makes a physical request from the server that is `a.com` ?

Comment: Making a request **on** a.com.

Comment: So there is a program or service running on the web server that runs a.com and when that program makes the request, it should get through, and all other visitors should not?

Comment: Yeah, sorry my grammar in the question is a little ambiguous. I am trying to make up some kind of virtual host environment without using the virtual host (actually I don't have access to it.)

I have a few domains pointing to the same machine and same document root folder. I managed to use .htaccess to forward requests coming **on** different domains to different folders _hiddenly_(no browser address bar change). But I couldn't figure out how to block direct access to those folders, e.g. using http://a.com/sites/b.com/.

Comment: Actually blocking access to /sites/ directory altogether would solve the problem but I couldn't find a way to do it without breaking the hidden forwarding, so I am trying to only allow access to http://a.com/sites/a.com, http://b.com/sites/b.com etc. at least and disable directory listing on /sites/

Comment: Ahh, makes sense. Do you have access to the central config?

Comment: All I have is .htaccess unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test this right now, but this piece of code stolen and modified from [here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/setenvif.html#HOST_Header_present_request) using `SetEnvIf` might help:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host "a.com" HTTP_MY_HAS_HOST
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=HTTP_MY_HAS_HOST
```

you can use regular expressions for the host name.

Comment: It did the job. This will actually solve a few more other problems I have. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi sir.Help needed! Please check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999860/changing-codeigniter-site-from-http-to-https-site-not-working/11999986#11999986)